# Native app authentication for Java EE 7 application

Tags: java, authentication, mobile, java-ee-7, keycloak

I've used Keycloak for authentication in services that are consumed only by web browsers, but now I'm facing the problem of building a JAX-RS application that will be consumed by native mobile apps on iOS and Android.

Keycloak provides a lot of the features I need, like: built-in support for combining multiple social logins and LDAP and/or Kerberos, self-service user registration and excellent management of authentication tokens and roles for different applications.

I'm aware of libraries from Aerogear that would allow me to add Keycloak to a mobile app, but I have a few concerns:

- Aerogear doesn't implement an AccountManager+SyncAdapter on Android. This seems completely wrong and makes me want to use something else, but I'm not aware of anything else that is designed to be quite so "plug and play" with Keycloak as Aerogear's Authz.
- If I implement my own authentication and authorization mechanism, I end up needing to do a lot more testing in order to ensure security of services and lose a lot of the benefits of operating in the Java EE environment to begin with.

What is the best way for me to implement native mobile access in Java EE 7? If it helps, I'm using Wildfly 10 and most clients will be on Android with some on iOS.

UPDATE: The best option I've found so far is to use an offline access token with Keycloak accessed with a custom account manager+sync adapter. Is this the best solution for me to go with?